# R: Picking values from matrix by indice matrix

Tags: r, matrix, subset, indices, picking

I have a datamatrix with n rows and m columns (in this case n=192, m=1142) and an indice matrix of nxp (192x114). Each row of the indice matrix shows the column numbers of the elements that I would like to pick from the matching row of the datamatrix. Thus I have a situation something like this (with example values):

```
data<-matrix(1:30, nrow=3)
data
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    1    4    7   10   13   16   19   22   25    28
[2,]    2    5    8   11   14   17   20   23   26    29
[3,]    3    6    9   12   15   18   21   24   27    30


columnindices<-matrix(sample(1:10,size=9, replace=TRUE),nrow=3)
columnindices
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    8    7    4
[2,]   10    8   10
[3,]    8   10    2
```

I would like to pick values from the datamatrix rows using the in columnindices matrix, so that the resulting matrix would look like this

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   22   19   10
[2,]   29   23   29
[3,]   24   30   6
```

I tried using a for loop:

```
result<-0
for(i in 1:3) {
 result[i]<-data[i,][columnindices[,i]]
 print[i]
}
```

but this doesn't show the wished result. I guess my problem should be rather simply solved, but unfortunately regardless many hours of work and multiple searches I still haven't been able to solve it (I am rookie). I would really appreciate some help!

Comment: Can you explain the rational behind the `columnindices`? You may try `columnindices<-matrix(sample(6:30,size=9, replace=TRUE),nrow=3)`

Comment: Here the formed columnindices matrix was just an example, in reality I have a specific column indices matrix that shows the columns of specific elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop is just a little bit off:

```
result <- matrix(rep(NA, 9), nrow = 3)
for(i in 1:3){
  result[i,] <- data[i, columnindices[i,]]
}

> result
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   25   13    7
[2,]   29   29   23
[3,]   15   15   18
```

Note that the matrix is not exactly the one you posted as expected result because the code for your example `columnindices` does not match the matrix you posted below. Code should work as you want it.

Comment: Thank you so much LAP! I was quite sure the solution would have to include some sort of subsetting of the matrix, but now I see it doesn´t.

Answer (score 0):

The `for`-loop way described by @LAP is easier to understand and to implement.

If you would like to have something universal, i.e. you don't need to 
adjust row number every time, you may utilise the `mapply` function:

```
result <- mapply(
  FUN = function(i, j) data[i,j],
  row(columnindices),
  columnindices)
dim(result) <- dim(columnindices)
```

`mapply` loop through every element of two matrices,

- row(columnindices) is for `i` row index
- columnindices is for `j` column index.

It returns a vector, which you have to coerce to the initial `columnindices` dimension.

Comment: A hint for someone using this function to large datasets (this may be obvious to some, but wasn't to me): it seems like the calculation can be speeded up considerably by converting data and columnindices to matrices. Tried this with an xts-object and the calculation never ended.